# Triple Boot - Mac, Windows, Backtrack

Tags: osx, windows, backtrack

This was the closest stackexchange site I could find to something of this nature.

Currently, I own a Macbook Pro with a Bootcamp Partition (Win7), a Mac Partition (OS X Lion), and the Recovery Partition that comes with the aforementioned Lion.

How do I go about creating a new partition with Backtrack on it?

Comment: Basically, shrink one or more existing partition, then create a new one in the empty space. What's your current partition layout? (Boot from a Linux live CD and post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.) Or run Backtrack in a VM!

Answer (score -1):

Shrink one of the partitions with gparted and use the so created space