# Will triple booting mess up my grub?

Tags: osx, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have installed Windows 10 alongside PeppermintOS 7 on my PC with grub, I followed [the advice in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175730/triple-booting-chromium-os-ubuntu-14-10-windows-7) and reserved free space to use as a partition. I now wish to install MacOS-X alongside the 2 that I already have.

#### So my questions are:

1. will the installation of MacOS mess up grub?
2. If not which is the safest method to do such a task without harming the other partitions?

**Note:** [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56064/triple-boot-mac-windows-backtrack) and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238587/triple-boot-windows-10-ubuntuwant-to-overwrite-with-linux-mint-and-kali-linu) are similar but didn't address my problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Probably. You'll have to deceive OSX into installing on your PC (if it's not a Mac). I am almost certain (won't try on mine) it'll thoroughly ignore Grub even on a Mac.

2) It could work if you installed OSX first and then let it do install Windows into a Bootcamp partition and then you installed Linux alongside Windows on that partition.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I won't take the risk of removing all my Operating Systems for the time being. According to what I understood from your answer, it is impossible to install macOSX by any normal means (e.a as if I would install another linux system), right?